# Jdbc connects to the database but won't retrieve rows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I'm making an application using Spring, Hibernate, Tomcat and Postgres. I just want to retrieve all the rows from my table and send them to localhost/clients.

My connection is working, I checked the information that I retrieve from my dataSource but I think that my domain class is not correct. Here it is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable= false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="age", nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @Column(name="numberofrentals", nullable = false)
    private int numberOfRentals;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="address", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(Integer id, int age, int numberOfRentals, String name, String address) {

        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.numberOfRentals = numberOfRentals;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRentals() {
        return numberOfRentals;
    }

    public void setNumberOfRentals(int numberOfRentals) {
        this.numberOfRentals = numberOfRentals;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Client client = (Client) o;

        if (age != client.age) return false;
        if (numberOfRentals != client.numberOfRentals) return false;
        if (!id.equals(client.id)) return false;
        if (!name.equals(client.name)) return false;
        return address.equals(client.address);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        result = 31 * result + numberOfRentals;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + address.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", numberOfRentals=" + numberOfRentals +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In my table called Client, I have id (PK), age, numberofrentals, address, name.

My controller looks like this:

```
RestController
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/clients", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.api+json")
    public @ResponseBody ClientsDto getClients() {
        List<Client> clientList = clientService.findAll();
        clientList.add(new Client(1,19,0,"gtttt","aaa"));
        return new ClientsDto(clientList);
    }
```

the clientService only has an empty repository that basically implements the JpaRepository.

The clientService implementation:

```
@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Client> findAll() {
        return clientRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Instead of an xml config I'm using a JPAConfig class. Here I also Enable the JPARepository giving it's path and I use the @COnfiguration to make sure that it's recognized. The JPAConfig class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("shop.tryHW.core.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class JPAConfig {

//    @Value("${db.jdbcURL}")
    private String jdbcURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Shop";

//    @Value("${db.user}")
    private String user = "postgres";

//    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password = "---------";

//    @Value("${db.generateDDL}")
    private Boolean generateDDL = true;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PGPoolingDataSource dataSource = new PGPoolingDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setUrl(jdbcURL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dataSource.setUser(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setMaxConnections(4);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(generateDDL);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("shop.tryHW.core.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        GuavaCacheManager guavaCacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager();
        guavaCacheManager.setCacheBuilder(CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(2, TimeUnit.HOURS));
        return guavaCacheManager;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

I have 2 entities in my table but I only get on my page the hardcoded one. What could be the problem? (I checked the datasource, and it actually sees all my tables from the database so that is ok I think). I don't get any errors, nothing related to the database. Is there a way to check what is happening?

Do I need more annotations at the Client entity?

Comment: Try deleting unique = true in your @Id column, maybe it works...

Comment: Didn't do anything noticeable

Comment: Is there source for ClientService?

Comment: I added the ClientService implementation. ClientRepository is just an interface that extends the JpaRepository

Comment: So what is the actual concrete runtime type of your clientRepository member variable?  i.e. what class implements the findAll() method?  You say clientService just has an empty repository, so I am not sure why you would expect it to return anything but an empty list.

Comment: The JpaRepository has that implemented as far as I know. I have JpaRepository enabled.http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

Comment: Hibernate is probably deleting & rebuilding your db on startup. Show us your persistence.xml file. you want hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate or update

Comment: I dont have a persistence.xml. I only have JPAConfig class and that's about it.